# For how much time a PHP extension is available in memory?

Tags: php, xampp, php-extension

I wrote a php extension, registered it in php.ini of XAMPP and I logged this events: module init, request init, request shutdown.

So, I can calculate the interval of each event like below:

> ===== INIT MODULE: 26/9/2019 10:20:58
>
> -INIT REQUEST: 26/9/2019 10:22:23
>
> -SHUTDOWN REQUEST: 26/9/2019 10:22:56   : 33
>
> -INIT REQUEST: 26/9/2019 10:23:9
>
> -SHUTDOWN REQUEST: 26/9/2019 10:23:9   : 0
>
> -INIT REQUEST: 26/9/2019 10:26:9
>
> -SHUTDOWN REQUEST: 26/9/2019 10:26:9   : 0

The interval of the first event is always the longest (33 seconds).
After that, the intevals are almost of 0 second. I think when the extension isn't called for a long time, it will go in a kind of sleep mode. 
So, for how much time a PHP extension will be available in memory before going into sleep?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Once an extension gets loaded, it will always be there in the memory. It neither goes to sleep mode as well. Otherwise, you would not get those logs.

Normally, first request takes time due to initialization. Afterwords, the request gets processed very quickly, hence the interval is 0.